# ActionBarSherLock divider style

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Does anyone knows,
How do i set a line in between ActionBar tab bar and title bar, because i am using same color for both, that looks odd, 
i am using style as:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/customActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>
```

here i set the color,

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#4B4B4B</item>
    <item name="background">#4B4B4B</item>
</style>
<style name="customActionBarTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="background">#4B4B4B</item>
    <item name="android:background">#4B4B4B</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this :

```
<style name="Theme.Dreams" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle.Dreams</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabBarStyle.Dreams" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_tabbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/ic_tabbar_divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
</style>
```